# replace exec function

Tags: php, imagemagick

I'm using exec function to do image resize in PHP using ImageMagick :

```
exec("convert $userfile -thumbnail $width x $height $userfile");
```

but the server support diabled this function and said it's unsafe, and i can't use it anymore

is there any other method to rezie image using ImageMagick rather than using exec ?

Comment: That looks like a worthy answer @Charles

Comment: What comment?  There was no comment there.  I have no idea what you're talking about.

Comment: @Charles but it was there, I SWEAR! *No, don't take me away again, it was really there, I saw it with my own eyes*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If they disabled `exec`, they probably disabled all the other ways to open processes.  Perhaps you should see if they'll install the ["imagick" PECL extension](http://pecl.php.net/package/imagick).

That or you can convert your code to use the built-in GD stuff instead.  Thumbnailing is easy.

I'd personally recommend using a well-developed third-party library for this.  [Imagine](https://github.com/avalanche123/Imagine) is pretty nifty, for example.

Comment: i own the server, but suppor is authorized to disable anything for customer saftey. i can install new packages, but please tell me what should i install ?

Comment: Imagemagick is already installed, what shoul i install to use " ImageMagick functions" ?

Comment: You will need to install the extension.  You can do this either by invoking the `pecl` command or searching for an OS package likely to be called `php-pecl-imagick`.  If you can tell me what OS you are using and what version of PHP is currently installed, I might be able to give you more precise instructions.

Comment: No.  [Image Magick](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php) is the name of a set of libraries and programs that perform image manipulation.  Your OS exposes the programs (like `convert`) as the package `ImageMagick`.  You can call the *library functions* from PHP by installing the linked PHP extension through PECL.

Comment: ok, i installed php-prcl-imgick, now i can use ImageMagick functions directly from php file , like: http://php.net/manual/en/imagick.scaleimage.php ?

Comment: Yes.  The examples given in the comments in that page should help you along further.  If you encounter any problems with it, you probably want to post a new question.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use the [ImageMagick functions](http://php.net/manual/en/book.imagick.php) directly from PHP.  For example, [`Imagick::scaleImage`](http://php.net/manual/en/imagick.scaleimage.php).

Comment: But only if they're installed.